Make first bar in waterfall chart no colour in plotly.js
I have a waterfall chart in plotly.js that I am trying to edit without any luck. The code and data look as such:
Data:
waterfallData = ['115.013205594399636', '-0.400842618817745', '2.291162911190306', '0.000000000000000', '-6.508903960138462']
waterfallLaebls = ['Initial Portfolio', 'Contribution by New Positions', 'Contribution by Divested Positions', 'Contribution by Coverage Change', 'Contribution by Existing Positions Change']
scatterData = ['115.013205594399636', '110.394621926633747']
scatterLabels = ['Initial Portfolio', 'Final Portfolio']
colourBy = ['100.000000000000000', '-0.350000000000000', '1.990000000000000', '0.000000000000000', '-5.660000000000000']

Code:
function positionsWaterfallChart(subject, waterfallData, waterfallLabels, scatterData, waterfallLabels, colorBy) {

let resultsList = [];

// Calculate the results and append them to the array
for (let i = 0; i < waterfallData.length; i++) {
    if (i === 0) {
        // First element, no previous element to subtract
        resultsList.push(waterfallData[i]);
    } else {
        // Subtract the last element from the current element
        let result = waterfallData[i] - waterfallData[i - 1];
        resultsList.push(result);
    }
}

const scatterTrace = {
    type: 'scatter',
    mode: 'markers',
    x: scatterLabels,
    y: scatterData,
    marker: { color: 'black', size: 15 } // Customize marker appearance
};


const waterfallTrace = [
    {
        type: 'waterfall',
        measure: resultsList,
        base: [null].concat(waterfallData.slice(0, -1)),
        x: waterfallLabels,
        y: waterfallData,
        increasing: { marker: { color: '#1f77b4' } },
        decreasing: { marker: { color: 'red' } },
        connector: { line: { width: 0 } }
    },
    scatterTrace
];

let layout = {
    title: {
        text: subject,
        font: { size: 24 }
    },
    showlegend: false
};

const config = { 'displayModeBar': false, 'responsive': true };

Plotly.newPlot(document.getElementById('attribution-bar-chart'), waterfallTrace, layout, config);
};

The output graph looks like this:

I want to set the first bar to have no colour so that it looks like it is not there. i built this with various CoPilot prompt but have hit a brick wall here. please could someone help.

Looking through the plotly.js docs, I found a property for opacity. Maybe declaring an array within your data for the opacity of each trace and then referencing that array within your graph.
Something like this...
waterfallOpacity = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]

and then...
const waterfallTrace = [
{
    type: 'waterfall',
    measure: resultsList,
    base: [null].concat(waterfallData.slice(0, -1)),
    x: waterfallLabels,
    y: waterfallData,
    increasing: { marker: { color: '#1f77b4' } },
    decreasing: { marker: { color: 'red' } },
    opacity: waterfallOpacity,
    connector: { line: { width: 0 } }
},
scatterTrace
];


It looks like a really good solution but it's not getting rid of the bar for me. Does it disappear for you?
